# @PostPersist @OneToMany mappedBy issue

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

this is my classes,

```
@Entity
class Advertisement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "advertisement")
    private List<AdvertisementCoupon> coupons = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostPersist
    public void onPostPersist() {
 EventPublisher.CURRENT.publishEvent(new AdvertisementCreatedEvent(this));
    }
}

@Entity
class AdvertisementCoupon {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Advertisement advertisement;
}

class TimelineEventListener {

    @EventListener
    public void onAdvertisementCreated(AdvertisementCreatedEvent event){

        if (timelineRepository.existsByUserIdAndAdvertisementId(
            event.getAdvertisement().getCreatedUser().getId(), 
            event.getAdvertisement().getId())) {

            return;
        }

        TimelineAdvertisement timelineAdvertisement = new TimelineAdvertisement(event.getAdvertisement().getCreatedUser(), event.getAdvertisement());
        timelineRepository.save(timelineAdvertisement);
    }
}
```

When @PostPersist is called, only advertisement is inserted (I print the sql).

In `onAdvertisementCreated` method, when `timelineRepository.existsByUserIdAndAdvertisementId` is called, `AdvertisementCoupon` is inserted, but it throws a `Column 'advertisement_id' cannot be null` exception.
The advertisement id is already generated.

How can I bypass this issue, thanks.

Comment: how about sharing your event listener?